# Show that if $f\in\mathcal L^1((a,b))$ has a weak derivative, then it has a continuous modification

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$, $I:=(a,b)$, $X,Y$ be $\mathbb R$-Banach spaces and $\iota$ be a continuous embedding of $X$ into $Y$.

If $p\in[1,\infty]$, say $f\in\mathcal L^1(I,X)$ has a weak derivative in $L^p(I,Y)$ if there is a $g\in\mathcal L^p(I,Y)$ with $$\int_I\varphi'\iota f\:{\rm d}\lambda=-\int_I\varphi g\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I).$$ In that case, $f':=g$.

> I would like to show that
>
> 1. if $f\in\mathcal L^1(I,X)$ has a weak derivative in $L^1(I,Y)$, then there is a $\tilde f\in C(I,Y)$ with $\iota f=\tilde f$ $\lambda$-a.e.
> 2. if $Y=X'$ and $X$ is continuously embedded into a Hilbert space $H$ via $\kappa:X\to H$, then in the situation of (1.) there is a $\tilde f\in C(I,Y)$ with $\kappa f=\tilde f$ $\lambda$-a.e.

Regarding (1.): It's easy to see that if $g\in\mathcal L^1(I,Y)$ and $c\in Y$, then $$f(t):=c+\int_{(a,\:t)}g\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\overline I$$ is continuous and weakly differentiable with $f'=g$.

Now, in the situation of (1.), by the aforementioned fact, $$g(t):=\int_{(a,\:t)}f'\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\overline I$$ is continuous and weakly differentiable with $$g'=f'\tag2.$$

Now, in [*Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models*](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781461459743) (Corollary II.4.2), the special case $X=Y=\mathbb R$ is considered and we can find the following argumentation

[image]

The mentioned lemma is the following:

[image]

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't get why the argumentation is that "complicated". By $(1)$ and $(2)$, it holds $$\int_I\varphi'(\iota f-g)\:{\rm d}\lambda=0\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I)\tag3.$$ Now, if $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I)$, then $$\psi(t):=\int_a^t\varphi(s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\in I$$ is obviously in $C_c^\infty(I)$ as well and we've got $\psi'=\varphi$. So, we can replace "$\varphi'$" in $(3)$ by "$\varphi$".

And now the du Bois-Reymond lemma should immediately yield $\iota f=g$ $\lambda$-a.e.. Am I missing something?

Regarding (2.): At the moment, I've got no idea why this follows and would need some help to tackle that problem.

Comment: Minor nitpick: you need the spaces $X,Y$ complete in order that the integrals (most likely Bochner) exist

Comment: @daw Yes, you're right. Thanks for noting.

Comment: This is explained quite nicely in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf . The Du bOis-Reymond lemma is Cor 6.33 in App 6A.

Comment: the answer to (2) is in App 6B (Hilbert triples). I think you want $\tilde f \in C(0,T;H)$.

Comment: @daw Thank you for the reference. I think I've solved question 1 in the meantime. It seems like my mistake was that $\psi$ is only compactly supported if $\int_I\varphi=0$. I've asked for that separately here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4145152/47771. Regarding your reference: Why is Corollary 6.3 assuming *local* integrability of $f:(0,T)\to X$? Since $(0,T)$ is relatively compact, isn't "local integrability" the same as "integrability" here?

Comment: in the case of an open interval $(0,T)$ a locally integrable function may have a singularity that prevents it from being integrable on $[0,T]$. e.g., $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is locally integrable on $(0,1)$ but not integrable on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @daw Are we both talking about *Lebesgue* integrability? Since a singleton (like $\{0\}$) is a Lebesgue null set, it holds $\int_{[0,\:T]}=\int_{(0,\:T)}$ when the integral is wrt the Lebesgue measure. So I don't get how there should be any difference between being (Lebesgue) integrable on $[0,T]$ or $(0,T)$.

Comment: You are right, this is not relevant for integrability. The function $1/x$ is locally integrable on $(0,1)$: every compact subset $K\subset (0,1)$ has positive distance to the origin. For ex, the interval $(0,\epsilon)$ is *not* compact in $(0,1)$ (for the same reason it is not compact in $\mathbb R$).

Comment: @daw Just to be sure: Are you agreeing to me that we "local integrability" and "integrability" coincide in the context of Corollary 6.3?

Comment: No! local integrability is strictly weaker than integrability: $1/x$ is locally integrable on $(0,1)$ but not integrable.