# If $\varphi\in C_c^\infty((a,b))$, then $\varphi=\psi'$ for some $\psi\in C_c^\infty((a,b))$ iff $\int_a^b\varphi(s)\:{\rm d}s=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$, $I:=(a,b)$ and $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(I)$.

I would like to show that

1. $\exists\psi\in C_c^\infty(I):\varphi=\psi'$;
2. $\int_I\varphi=0$

are equivalent.

The direction "$\Rightarrow$" is easy to show. For the other direction, let $$\psi(t):=\int_a^t\varphi(s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\in I.$$ Clearly, $\psi$ is infinitely differentiable and $\psi'=\varphi$. But why does $$0=\int_I\varphi=\psi(b)\tag1$$ imply that $\operatorname{supp}\psi$ is a compact subset of $I$?

Comment: Just for the sake of the reader who wants to compare the whole exercise: the easy side follows from FTC applied to $\psi'$.

Comment: Another quick note. By my understanding, the definition of $C_c^\infty(I) $ usually refers to the topology on $ \mathbb{R} $ instead of that on $I$.

Comment: @KenHung What do you mean precisely? If I'm not wrong, $C_c(I)$ should consists of functions $I\to\mathbb R$ whose support is compact in $I$. With this definition, this generalizes to arbitrary topological spaces $I$.

Comment: What I meant is that since $I$ sits in $\mathbb{R}$, the compactness of the support means that the support is compact with respect to the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ instead of the subspace topology on $I$. But maybe I am wrong about this.

Comment: @KenHung I think, in light of the definition of $C_c(I)$ in my previous comment, this would be inconsistent with $C_c^\infty=C_c\cap C^\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a<c<d<b$ be such that the support of $\varphi$ is contained in $[c,d]$. Then $\int_c^d{\varphi}=0$, thus $\psi(x)=0$ if $x \notin [c,d]$.